# Prove whether the linear equations are solvable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I am beginner to linear algebra. I am confused for finding the solution for following question.
There are set of linear equation(m equations and n unknown) represented in the form of matrices.

matrix(m x n) * vector(n) = Vector(m).

Now how would i prove that the solution exist for the set of linear equation for the following cases:
1) if m > n
2) if m = n
3) else m < n
Q: Now consider the matrix(mxn) as input of function(which if vector(n)) and producing the output vector(m). So i want to know in which of the above three conditions the functions can be onto, one-to-one or both and why?

Answer (score 0):

The function corresponding to an $m \times n$ matrix is onto if and only if the matrix has rank $m$.  It is one-to-one if and only if it has rank $n$.  The rank is at most $m$ and at most $n$, so in case (1) it can never be onto, and in case (3) it can never be one-to-one.  Only in case (2) is it possible for the function to be both one-to-one and onto.